# Hibernate is not releasing MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate. I am creating some basic hibernate program to doing some insert into MySql database.  The below is the main code I have written. Although I am closing the session after transaction and seeing that " Released JDBC connection" on console, I can see an inactive connection in the database after running the program. Every time I am running the program a new inactive connection is getting created in the database. I have to click "terminate" button in eclipse console to stop that inactive session every time.

```
Student s1 = new Student();
s1.setName("Monaj");
s1.setRoll(1);
s1.setDate(new Date());

Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
sessionFactory = configuration.configure()
    .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction t1=session.beginTransaction();
session.save(s1);
t1.commit();
session.close();
```

Console output:-

```
15:29:08.476 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Aggressively releasing JDBC connection
15:29:08.476 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
15:29:08.476 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
15:29:08.477 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
15:29:37.323 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.h.e.j.c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - Connection pool now considered primed; min-size will be maintained
```

Hibernate Configuration:-

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
<property name="connection.password">password</property>
<property name="connection.username">admin</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name="connection.release_mode">AFTER_TRANSACTION</property>
<property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>
```

Could anyone please help me with this.

================================Adding Analysis ===========================

for Server there is a fix for this issue like when using IBM WebSphere, there is a option for minimum connection pool. if we make it 0. I think it will get resolved.

But for standalone application with eclipse, not sure what is wrong. :(

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Comment: I could not. Not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the connection release mode to "auto"

```
<property name="connection.release_mode">auto</property>
```

Refer to this [manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/transactions-connection-release.html) for more info.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried using all the value but the issue is still there. I am closing the sessionfactory also. but still I am getting the same. I can see it is closing the jdbc connection but I can see the inactive connection in the database.         | Id | User  | Host            | db   | Command | Time | State | Info             |
| 38 | admin | localhost:54151 | test | Sleep   |  361 |       | NULL             |
| 41 | admin | localhost:54213 | test | Sleep   |  118 |       | NULL             |
| 42 | admin | localhost:54220 | test | Sleep   |   44 |       | NULL             |

Comment: Finally, was there a solution for this issue?

Comment: No molavec. Did not get any solution . so I left it.